# Listener events to change style of fusion table in google maps

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I want to add a event listener that changes the stroke of a polygon when the user puts the mouse over it.

But Google Fusion Tables doesn't have `mouseover` and `mouseout` events.

```
//Mousover Event
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'mouseover', function() {
    this.setOptions({strokeWeight: 3});
});

//Mouseout Event
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'mouseout', function() {
    this.setOptions({strokeWeight: 1});
});
```

Is there any trick that I could handle that in another manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no `mouseover`/`mouseout`-events, FusionTablesLayer only supports the `click`-event.